# How do I revert Windows Explorer's view to remove categories?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

How do I get Windows Explorer back to a normal layout and get rid of this category nonsense?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this Windows support page: [Arrange, sort, or group your files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/arrange-sort-or-group-your-files)

Right click inside the folder, select *Group by* and select *(None)*.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: If it's a special folder like "Pictures" (or an 'open dialog') and you see "Arrange by:" (top-right), you also have to pick arrange by "Name" - there is no way to turn off grouping otherwise.